# how to change the order of words before and after underscore in R

Tags: r

how to change order of words before and after underscore

For example

1. hello_wor -> wor_hello
2. hi_everyone -> everyone_hi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could do:

```
sub("(.*)_(.*)", "\\2_\\1", str1)
```

```
[1] "wor_hello"   "everyone_hi"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use regex to do this i.e. capture the words (`(\\w+)`) before and after the `_` and in the replacement rearrange the backreferences

```
sub("^(\\w+)_(\\w+)$", "\\2_\\1", str1)
[1] "wor_hello"   "everyone_hi"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("hello_wor", "hi_everyone")
```

Answer (score 2):

With `tidyverse` approach:

```r
library(tidyverse)

words <- c("Peter_Gabriel", "Tina_Turner")

map_chr(words, ~ str_extract_all(.x, "\\w+(?=_)|(?<=_)\\w+") 
    %>% flatten %>% rev %>% paste0(collapse = "_"))

#> [1] "Gabriel_Peter" "Turner_Tina"
```