# gsub replace word not followed by : with word: R

Tags: r, regex

I thought this would be simpler, but I have strings not followed by ':', and strings with `:` inside the string. I want to append `:` to strings that don't end in `:`, and ignore strings that have `:` inside.

```
words
[1] "Bajos"    "Ascensor" "habs.:3"
gsub('\\b(?!:)', '\\1:', words, perl = TRUE)
[1] ":Bajos:"     ":Ascensor:"  ":habs:.::3:"
grep('\\W', words)
[1] 3
grep('\\w', words)
[1] 1 2 3 # ?
```

Desired output:

```
'Bajos:' 'Ascensor:' 'habs.:3'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```r
"(\\p{L}+)\\b(?![\\p{P}\\p{S}])"
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/MNMBxW/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (\p{L}+)                 one or more letters (group #1) 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       word boundary
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?![\p{P}\p{S}])         no punctuation allowed on the right
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**R code snippet**:

```r
gsub("(\\p{L}+)\\b(?![\\p{P}\\p{S}])", "\\1:", text, perl=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
sub("^([^:]*)$", "\\1:", words)
# [1] "Bajos:"    "Ascensor:" "habs.:3"
```

or

```r
nocolon <- !grepl(":", words)
words[nocolon] <- paste0(words[nocolon], ":")
words
# [1] "Bajos:"    "Ascensor:" "habs.:3"
```

Comment: The idea is to only have trailing `:`, not before and after, hence the `Bajos:` above, whereas, leave alone anything with interior `:`.  The trajectory is towards a `write.dcf` where unadorned strings are rendered tags: (empty tags in these cases).

Comment: Oops, need to check my glasses, I thought for sure there were leading colons too. Fixed.

Comment: I like your `sub(` above as it is agnostic to encoding. That came up latter with the @ryszard-czech accepted,`bañ:os:2", "m:²:72"` though wasn't revealed as a concern given the strings I chose for example data. That said, it was too weary-brain late to `iconv` to common ground, then apply the regex. It also developed that making .dcf records worked best earlier in process so strings [words] ended with `\n\n`, unlike example, after your sub, `\n\n:`, just need to  `gsub{`ed out. The [OP ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73661728/splitting-text-by-and-populating-a-table/73670422#73670422)